# Manipulate date field pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is a quickest way to manipulate date field in pandas data frame, such as replacing date's day value to the last day of the month. Currently I can do following but it takes long to run.

```
import calendar
consumption_data_monthly.DATE = consumption_data_monthly.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(x.year,x.month)[1]))
```

Comment: IIUC you could use `consumption_data_monthly.DATE.dt.days_in_month` should return maximum days in the considering month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `calendar.monthrange` is very effective and very quick, but vectorization is faster.

You can try convert column `DATE` to month's `numpy` array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), then add next `month` and substract one `day`:

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[M]') + 
             np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[M]') - 
             np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

Timing `len(df)=70000`:

```
In [468]: %timeit one(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 881 ms per loop

In [469]: %timeit two(df1)
1 loops, best of 3: 733 ms per loop

In [470]: %timeit three(df2)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.24 s per loop

In [471]: %timeit four(df3)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.61 ms per loop

In [472]: %timeit five(df4)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.76 ms per loop
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

d = {'DATE': {0: pd.Timestamp('2012-01-05 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2012-02-08 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2012-03-11 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2012-04-06 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2012-05-04 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2012-06-20 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2012-07-09 00:00:00')}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df

df =  pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()
df4 = df.copy()

def one(df):
    df.DATE = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(x.year,x.month)[1]))
    return df

def two(df):    
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, x.month, calendar.monthrange(x.year,x.month)[1]))
    return df

def three(df):    
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, x.month, x.days_in_month))
    return df

def four(df): 
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[M]') + np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[M]') - np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
    return df

def five(df):    
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'] + MonthEnd()
    return df

print one(df).head()
print two(df1).head()
print three(df2).head()
print four(df4).head()
```

Timing `len(df)=7`:

```
In [475]: %timeit one(df)
The slowest run took 11.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 379 µs per loop

In [476]: %timeit two(df1)
The slowest run took 11.93 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 336 µs per loop

In [477]: %timeit three(df2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 398 µs per loop

In [478]: %timeit four(df3)
The slowest run took 19.07 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 159 µs per loop

In [479]: %timeit five(df4)
The slowest run took 4.89 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) to add the month end to your dates:

```
In [25]:
df['DATE'] + MonthEnd()
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df['DATE'] + MonthEnd()

Out[25]:
0   2012-01-31
1   2012-02-29
2   2012-03-31
3   2012-04-30
4   2012-05-31
5   2012-06-30
6   2012-07-31
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Timings**

```
In [26]:
def four(df): 
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[M]') + np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[M]') - np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
    return df
​
%timeit four(df)
%timeit df['DATE'] = MonthEnd()
1000 loops, best of 3: 206 µs per loop
The slowest run took 272.78 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 139 µs per loop
```

You can see that using offsets is faster than the suggested solution

On a 70K row df the timings are:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 5.69 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8 ms per loop
```

So the other solution is faster for larger dfs, here the syntax is cleaner

Comment: I think it is faster in small dataframes, in larger not.

Comment: @jezrael added new timings, yes your solution is quicker, usually using pure np will always beat pandas the tradeoff will be some nicer `NaN` handling and syntax